# How do I encrypt data in Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, encryption, ef-code-first

I've been trying and failing to figure out a good approach to encrypting SQL data with the Entity Framework Code First. I must preface this with that I am hosting in Azure and do not have access to native SQL encryption.

Taking a page from [SecurEntity](http://securentity.codeplex.com/), I have fully implemented an approach that utilizes SaveChanges and ObjectMaterialized to handle the encrypting/decrypting of the entities, but in testing I have found this has been far too unreliable to use.

Here is a sample of some of the implementation:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var pendingEntities = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
        .Where(en => !en.IsRelationship).ToList();

    foreach (var entry in pendingEntities) //Encrypt all pending changes
        EncryptEntity(entry.Entity);

    int result = base.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var entry in pendingEntities) //Decrypt updated entities for continued use
        DecryptEntity(entry.Entity);

    return result;
}

void ObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
{
    DecryptEntity(e.Entity);
}
```

I've seen other posts that manually encrypt/decrypt via secondary properties, like so:

```
public Value { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public DecryptedValue
{
    get { return Decrypt(this.Value); }
    set { this.Value = Encrypt(value); }
}
```

This will most definitely work, but I find this approach to be... less than ideal. When using this approach, all the developers have to wade through all the encrypted properties to find which ones they can use.

The most ideal solution would be for me to be able to override the getting/setting of each value at the data-access level. Is there a way to do this? If not, how can I implement data encryption with Entity Framework - Code First so that it will be easy to maintain and work with?

Comment: Be aware that the current implementation of SecurEntity has a fatal security flaw, which means that the key generated from the certificate is actually never used. For a quick and dirty fix, see https://securentity.codeplex.com/workitem/7376

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have good news. The instability I was experiencing with the SaveChanges/ObjectMaterialized approach was due to the fact that `DetectChanges()` isn't called until the DbContext actually performs the save.

I was able to fix this by calling `DetectChanges()` before I pulled the Added/Modified records from the `ObjectStateManager`. This cleared up any object state oddities that were causing inconsistent encryption behavior.

The resulting code being:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var contextAdapter = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this);

    contextAdapter.ObjectContext.DetectChanges();

    var pendingEntities = contextAdapter.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
        .Where(en => !en.IsRelationship).ToList();

    foreach (var entry in pendingEntities) //Encrypt all pending changes
        EncryptEntity(entry.Entity);

    int result = base.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var entry in pendingEntities) //Decrypt updated entities for continued use
        DecryptEntity(entry.Entity);

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT** - Added a sample DataContext to see my end-to-end solution for encrypting all entities. Note: You don't have to use a custom attribute for encrypting properties. [Source](https://gist.github.com/albertbori/e95860644e69c1572441)

Comment: is there a way to override all properties GET methods to decrypt them? I dont want to have to do this on a per object basis, can we override it on a global level, then loop the properties and decrypt any string properties?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, but it is possible to modify the properties of all objects when they are saved/retrieved in EntityFramework. That's exactly what `EncryptEntity ` and `DecryptEntity` in my sample code does. I'll add those two methods to my answer for reference.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your version of EncryptionService? If not, could you give me some guidance on how to achieve this? I have tried looking for this but haven't had much success on things like where to store the encryption keys, etc.

Comment: @parth-shah, I will post an example of the full approach I'm using. However, encryption key storage is its own problem. I use [Azure's app config settings feature](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) to set the production encryption keys. But there's a [whole industry that provides secure encryption key storage solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_management). It's a very difficult problem, because as long as the data can be accessed by a trusted entity, hackers could potentially get to the data as well